# How to mimick Weighted LinearLayout with a Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How can we spare space equally in a Constraint Layout as in LinearLayout?
For instance, how would the below layout become if it was written with constraints?

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="A"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="B"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="C"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="D"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In a Constraint Layout, I could set `A` and `D` to the edges, `A←B→D` with a 33 bias and `A←C→D` with a 66 bias to kind of have equal space between each element.
That solution does not really scale though.

Is there a proper way to do this in Constraint Layout?

Comment: Do you really need the items directly in the ConstraintLayout, or can you put them in the linearlayout, and put the linearlayout into the ConstraintLayout

Comment: @lionscribe ConstraintLayout are here to, among other things, make flat design and help perf. I am therefore looking for a way to do this in a flat way, without any other nested layout.

Comment: There's new documentation for this at https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

FYI -- [Constraint Layout alpha 9](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayoutalpha9isnowavailable) added [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains), which allow you to implement this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Can you please update any sample code. I can't able to find that option in Android studio 2.2.2 layout editor like Add Vertical Guideline & Add Horizontal Guideline

Comment: @ramji it's not available in the 2.2.2 UI, you will have to modify the XML for now. You can check the Chains documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Answer (score 8):

At the moment (constraint layout alpha 6) the only other option to do this is to use vertical guidelines with a percent position, then for each widget constrain them to the guidelines in such a way:
Left side <- widget A -> Guideline 1 <- widget B -> Guideline 2 <- widget C -> Right side

With Guideline 1 at 0.33, Guideline 2 at 0.66.

But.

While it works, I doubt it would be faster than using linear layout for this specific task -- if all you want is this exact behaviour, just use linear layout (even inside a constraint layout). The only advantage that it gives you to do it with constraint layout is that you can define this behaviour only for a given axis, the other axis could be constrained completely differently (while for LL it will be aligned -- but that's the common need).

Although we do have plans to make this particular behaviour a lot easier to do in future versions of constraint layout, it doesn't mean that all the existing layouts should never be used anymore.

Comment: I used a similar approach but as you know, it does not scale ; we need to redefine those guidelines if a widget is added/removed. Thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: Yep -- that's why we are planning on adding another mechanism for this in ConstraintLayout. But using a linear layout in that case is fine as well.

Answer (score -2):

For example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ButtonA"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_b" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ButtonB"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_a"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_c" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ButtonC"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_b"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```